# Add element to the "Add new comment" link

Tags: 8, navigation, theming

I'm using a Bootstrap theme and would like to add a glyphicon to the "Add new comment" link so that it comes out something like this:

```
<a href="..."><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Add new comment</a>
```

I've considered overriding the link's default text, but I'm not sure how to do it for this string of text, and I don't like the idea of adding HTML to a translatable string.

Using `THEME_preprocess_links(&$variables)`, I used [Kint](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to explore `$variables['links']['comment-add']`, but I couldn't find any public methods that would allow me to edit the link contents.

Comment: I am not sure about adding a span inside the link, but cant that THEME_preprocess_links add css classes by ['attributes'] to the link itself?

Comment: Yep, see [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/186175/edit-read-more-and-add-new-comment-links-in-teaser-in-drupal-8). But adding the glyphicon class directly to the `<a>` element isn't [how it's done in bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use) and it affects the formatting of the link's content.

Comment: Bootstrap glyphicons need their own span with no content and no other classes. I usually build this kind of bootstrap with inline templates (the fastest way), but the correct way would be to build a custom link template for this.

Comment: Not sure how a custom link template will help here. Links are generated via [\Drupal\Core\Utility\LinkGenerator](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Utility!LinkGenerator.php/function/LinkGenerator%3A%3Agenerate/8) from what I can tell, which does: `return $generated_link->setGeneratedLink('<a' . $attributes . '>' . $variables['text'] . '</a>');`. It looks like I'd need to form a new link and edit the `$variables['text']` section...

Comment: See comment_node_links_alter() and \Drupal\comment\CommentLinkBuilder::buildCommentedEntityLinks()

Comment: You can't put the span in $variables['text'], it will get escaped. You can generate for any html element your own template and then put a render array with '#template => 'mytemplate' in your field variable['comment-add'].